How do I use numpys interpolation with xarrays
I have some code that does a linear interpolation on data.
In the case where the data is numpy arrays it works as I would expect.
amplitude = np.interp(reflected_times, times, trace)

gives (zoomed in to show the interpolation clearly):

However when I do a similar process on xarray.DataArrays:
amplitude = np.interp(reflected_times, times, trace)

It doesnt work. Images of the plot zoomed without any zoom, and a couple zoomed in:



It looks a bit at the start like the plot is simply shifted, but that isnt the case if y ou look further on - the interpolation is just not being done correctly.
I expect this is something obvious particular to xarrays that I am clearly misunderstanding - can anyone suggest what the issue might be?
It is worth noting that I am using Dask distributed with a local cluster, and I have a list of tasks that do the interpolation for a data set which I am using delayed and compute to run them:
tasks = [
    delayed(self._method_that_does_the_interpolation)(
        inputs, for, the, method
    )
    for cmp_index in range(min_cmp, max_cmp + 1)
]

with self.dask_context() as dc:
    results = compute(*tasks, scheduler=dc)

and in the class method that does the interpolation I am converting the dask arrays to xarray before the interpolation:
times = xr.DataArray(times)  
trace = xr.DataArray(trace)
reflected_times = xr.DataArray(reflected_times,dims="reflected_times")

and I am starting to wonder if the interpolation is being done correctly but for some reason the data I am outputting to plot isnt corresponding i.e. i am plotting the interpolation for a different data set.
Edit
The above is exactly what was happening. When I switch to a single threaded scheduler the data output is correct and the interpolation is being done properly.

Have you thought to use https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.interp.html ?

Thanks @mdurant - I'll take a look at the xarray version!
